# Storing data from a Textbox from within a GridView

Tags: asp.net

This code `TextBox tx1 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("TextBox1");`

I know it grabs the data from the textbox1 within a GridView , and stores in a Textbox type.  What other options do I have to store using this code above, e.g can I store it in a DateTime type?

Cheers

Comment: I'm afraid that i don't understand the _question_ and i'm rather sure that i'm not alone.

Comment: DateTime MyDate = Convert.ToDateTime(((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl).Text)

Comment: Interestingly why (textbox) in brackets?  I thought the findcontrol would be sufficient.

Comment: @TeaDrinkingGeek..   Because you need to explicitly cast it(Founded control) to the 'Textbox'..

Answer (score 0):

The article describes how to store the values in the database using the code:

```
sqlcon = new SqlConnection(con);
   sqlcon.Open();
   string sql = "update employee set emp_name='" + 
    tx1.Text + "',emp_address='" + tx2.Text + "',salary='" +
    tx3.Text + "',department='" + ddl.SelectedValue.ToString() 
    + "',maritalstatus='" + rbl.SelectedValue.ToString() + "',Active_status='" 
        + chb.SelectedValue.ToString() + "' where emp_id='" +
   lb.Text + "'";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql);
   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
   cmd.Connection = sqlcon;
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery ();
   GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
   showgrid ();
```

in protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)

Do you want to store the value in the database ?

Comment: Like GLK.net said, use Convert.ToDateTime or DateTime.Parse to convert the string to DateTime. Convert has a lot of other usefull conversion methods also.    DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(tx1.Text) in your case since you already have tx1.